# How does AngularJS resolves call to variables on $scope in 2 or more controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/scope-hierarchy.html), the author mentions

> ```
> the $scope object used by the two controllers are not the same $scope object
> ```

Snippet for the same:

[image]

[image]

Now consider a little modification to the above code.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myController1">

        <div>{{data.theVar}}</div>
        <div>{{data.common}}</div>

        <div ng-controller="myController2">
            <div>{{data.theVar}}</div>
            <div>{{data.common}}</div>
            <div>{{temp}}</div>
            <div>{{newTemp}}</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        var module = angular.module("myapp", []);
        var myController1 = module.controller("myController1", function($scope) {
            $scope.data = { 
                theVar : "Value One",
                common : "common Value"
            };

            $scope.temp = "John Wick 2 is going to be released soon";
        });

        var myController2 = module.controller("myController2", function($scope) {
            $scope.data = { 
                theVar : "Value Two"
            };

            $scope.newTemp = $scope.temp;
            console.log("");

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The view corresponding to controller2 has been moved inside the view for controller1.

For this piece of code inside the controller2,

```
$scope.newTemp = $scope.temp;
```

[image]

> Are $scope highlighted above one and the same object?
>
> If yes, how does AngularJS know this?

Had they been same, `$scope.temp` in controller2 would be undefined and so then `$scope.newTemp`?

For me, they are not the same, considering the ***o/p*** of the above program. See below:

[image]

But then, I am perplexed as to why they both comes out to be one & the same when I debug, 
[image]

How does AngularJS able to access value of `$scope.temp` from controller1 in controller2?
Please clarify?

Lastly,

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Altough it's true that the `$scope` used in two controllers are not the same, they can inherit eachother's properties. Angular's `$scope`s are like a tree, the trunk is the `$rootScope` and every other `$scope` branches from that or another `$scope`, so since your `myController2` is a child of `myController1` you can access the variables in it.

```
$rootScope -> myController1 -> myController2
```

The `myController2` can access all the parent `$scope`s, the `myController1` can access `$rootScope` and the `$rootScope` can only access itself.

Comment: Why doesn't the Google Chrome debugger show then the properties (referring to $scope of controller1) in $scope of controller2?

Comment: It does, but it's inside `__proto__`

Comment: Martijn: Oh, yes. Didn't notice that basic point. Well, thank you for the same.

Comment: The exception to the rule being if you use an isolate scope - in those cases, the scope will *not* inherit from parent scopes (but will inherit from rootScope).

Answer (score 3):

For your last part, as both controllers have property by name `data`, angular will look into current scope first and then hierarchically move up i.e. parent's scope. Therefore, angular founds `data` in second controller's scope itself and hence need not refer parent's scope `data` variable. But there is no `common` key inside that property and hence does not output anything out.

Do look into `controller as` syntax of angular, it is meant to keep these conflicts at bay.